# Is it safe to compare a float and an int in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

Is it safe to compare a float and an integer like this?

```
private static void foo(float n) {
    if (n >= 1 || n <= 0) {
      // code 
    } 
}
```

According to the [JLS (5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) if one of the parameters is `float`, the other is converted to `float` before comparison.
But as far as I understand, such a comparison will return true if the converted float is binary identical to the original float. How can we ensure it?

Comment: Yes. It's safe. Note it's a `double` rather than a `float` here - but the same rules apply.

Comment: @MattBall:  Good catch.  I apparently need more coffee.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, your specific example is fine, since both `0` and `1` can be exactly represented as a `float`.

Note that this is not true in general: there are many large `int` values that's can't be represented exactly as a `float`. For example, the following prints out `true` ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/X0k9Oc)) even though 2_000_000_001 does not equal 2_000_000_000:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class FloatTest {

    private static boolean isTwoBillion(float f) {
        return f == 2_000_000_000;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isTwoBillion(2_000_000_001));
    }

}
```

Note that, unlike `float`, `double` has wide enough mantissa to store every 32-bit `int` value.

However, there are `long` values that cannot be represented as `double`s.  This starts occurring at `long` value `9_223_372_036_854_764` which is `Long.MAX_VALUE/1000 - 10`.  The number one greater (`...765`) has no `double` counterpart, while the following number (`...766`) does.  Put another way, starting with `...764` as a `double`, incrementing the last bit of the mantissa gives `...766` when converted back to `long`.

Comment: That would be amazing if you gave an example

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev: I've added an example.

Comment: @NPE your answer is used as a dup target so I added some info on `long` vs `double`.